# Can we set nifi processor group level variable based on value coming from some processor inside the same processor group

Tags: apache-nifi

In my flow, there is one Main processor group inside it I have multiple processor groups.
Usually, I will define variables at Main processor group level and use inside the Main processor group.

Is there any possibility to define a **variable** at Main Processor Group whose value may be coming from some processor which is inside of `MainProcesserGroup>>SomeChildProcessorGroup`.

I tried the below approach,

1. Drag an UpdateAttribute processor onto the canvas and connect it to the processor whose value you want to capture.
2. Configure the UpdateAttribute processor to add a new user-defined property, for example, "myVariable", and set its value to the value you want to capture from the previous processor.
3. Go to the Processor Group Properties tab and add a new user-defined property, for example, "groupVariable".
4. Set the value of "groupVariable" to the NiFi expression that references the "myVariable" attribute that was added in the UpdateAttribute processor.

For example, if the "myVariable" attribute added in the UpdateAttribute processor has a value of "123", you could set the value of "groupVariable" to "${myVariable}".

Assuming the value of "groupVariable" will be set to the value of "myVariable" for every flowfile that passes through the processor group.

But didn't worked.

So, could someone please suggest the better approach if this is possible.